# Rename [writetofile] tag to [objective-c-writetofile]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [writetofile](/questions/tagged/writetofile) tag is defined as:

> for questions concerning the writeToFile method, part of the NSData class in OS X and iOS

But due to the tag's generic name, at least half of the questions with this tag are questions about writing data to files in Python, Java, PHP, C# and other languages.

Proposal: rename this tag [objective-c-writetofile](/questions/tagged/objective-c-writetofile), or [nsdata-writetofile](/questions/tagged/nsdata-writetofile), or something else more descriptive than the current tag.

Alternatively, as suggested, delete the tag entirely if it's not really useful for categorizing questions -- I'm agnostic on that particular resolution.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that the description is wrong.

The name of the method is `writeToFile:atomically:`, so the tag doesn't even have the right name.

Further, it's either broad enough to be covered by [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io), or way too specific of a tag. If it's about the particular method, then that is really a *subject*, not a *topic*, and it can be covered in the title and summary.

It's just not useful for categorizing questions. I say destroy it.

Comment: I'm not an OSX or iOS programmer, so I don't have any opinion on whether it's useful for categorizing in the first place. I'm fine with this solution too. :-)